# The workflow template has specified no FormURN for this page Error when Associating Out of the box SharePoint 2010 publihsing approval workflow

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

Hello i have associated a imported a out of the box SharePoint 2010 Publishing Approval Workflow from Sharepoint Designer 2013 to Visual studio 2012 with the import Sharepoint 2010 workflow project in Visual Studio.
I have also Assocaited the workflow with C# like you see below:

```
 public void AddWorkflowAssociationToPagesList(SPList assoicationList, string spWorkflowTemplateGuid)
        {

            try
            {

                SPWorkflowTemplate workflowTemplate =
                    _web.WorkflowTemplates.GetTemplateByBaseID(new Guid(spWorkflowTemplateGuid));

                if (workflowTemplate == null) { _logger.LogError(LoggingCategory.Workflow, "Error in associating workflow with guid: " + spWorkflowTemplateGuid + " The workflowtemplate does not exist in: " + _web.MasterUrl); }

                SPList pagesList = _web.Lists[PublishingWeb.GetPagesListName(_web)];

                if (workflowTemplate != null)
                {
                    var taskList = _listProvisioner.TryGetList(_web, _localaizedWorkFlowTaskList, string.Empty, true, SPListTemplateType.Tasks);
                    var historyList = _listProvisioner.TryGetList(_web, _localaizedWorkFlowHistoryList, string.Empty, true, SPListTemplateType.WorkflowHistory);

                    SPWorkflowAssociation workflowAssocaition = SPWorkflowAssociation.CreateListAssociation(workflowTemplate,_workflowAssociationName, taskList, historyList);
                    assoicationList.WorkflowAssociations.Add(workflowAssocaition);

                    _web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    assoicationList.DefaultContentApprovalWorkflowId = workflowAssocaition.Id;
                    assoicationList.Update();
                    _web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                }
            }
             catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(LoggingCategory.Workflow, "Error: " + ex + " in associating workflow with id: " + spWorkflowTemplateGuid);                
            }   
        }
```

The error occurs when i try to publish a page in the pages library:
The workflow template has specified no FormURN for this page

The ULS Log gives me this on the correlation id:

```
Application error when access /_layouts/15/IniWrkflIP.aspx, Error=The workflow template has specified no FormURN for this page.  
 at Microsoft.Office.Workflow.IniWrkflIPPage.LoadFromWorkflowAssociation()    
 at Microsoft.Office.Workflow.IniWrkflIPPage.OnLoad(EventArgs ea)    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() 
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean    includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

This does not occur if i change the start condition of the workflow to start when creating a new item in the library, only when starting the workflow by publishing a page.

Has anyone experienced this kind of problem before ?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to publish it from the ribbon on the page itself? Unfortunately that part is fully dependent on the start form being an InfoPath form instead of an ASP.Net form. Yet if you try and publish it via checkin/major or Publish a Major Version via the context menu on the Pages library, you'll find that it will work correctly. Let me know if you're getting the same behavior both ways, or if its solely on the buttons in the ribbon on the page itself.